# Jquery, ajax and JSON: Parsing GET response fails, but only sometimes?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, json, ajax

I  am doing an ajax call with jquery which returns a json array and it works fine on some cases. On other cases however, the browser (ff and IE11) cannot parse the response. I'm including my script in my .jsp file like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="../scripts/test.js"></script>
```

This is the structure of the json as shown in my servlet in the java console:

```
[{"key":"...","type":"...","content":"..."},
 {"key":"...","type":"...","content":"..."},
 ...]
```

My request simply looks like this:

```
var url = document.location.origin + "/Servlet",
        searchText = $("input[name=search]").val(),
        types = getOptions();


$.ajaxSetup({
    type: "GET",
    url: url, 
    data: {"operation": "search", "searchText": searchText, "types": types, "resultNumber": 200},
    datatype: "json",
    success: function(result,status,xhr)
    {
        showResults(result);  
    },
    cache: false
});

$.ajax();
```

My java method for creating the JSON array:

```
private JSONArray parseJSON (ArrayList<ResultObject> aResultList) throws JSONException
    {
        JSONArray resultJSONArray = new JSONArray();

        for (ResultObject resultObject : aResultList)
        {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            HashMap<String,String> fields = resultObject.getFields();

            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : fields.entrySet())
            {
                jsonObject.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
            }
            resultJSONArray.put(jsonObject);
        }
        return resultJSONArray;
    }
```

The servlet response looks like this:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest aRequest, HttpServletResponse aResponse) 
    throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
                QueryObject queryObject = new QueryObject();
                queryObject.setSearchText(aRequest.getParameter("searchText"));
                String[] types = aRequest.getParameterValues("types[]");
                queryObject.setTypes(types);
                queryObject.setResultNumber(Integer.parseInt(aRequest.getParameter("resultNumber")));

                JSONArray results = indexManager.doSearch(queryObject);

                System.out.println(results.toString());

                aResponse.getWriter().write(results.toString());

        aResponse.setContentType("application/json");
//      aResponse.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = aResponse.getWriter();
        out.flush();
    }
```

I parse it with jquery like this:

```
function showResults (resultList)
{
    $.each(resultList, function(i, item) 
        {
            console.log(item.key);
        });
}
```

Debugging shows me that sometimes the returned JSONarray is not parsed to JSON automatically but stays as a string, which is why `$.each(..)` fails. I could not determine why jquery has a problem parsing it, since it doesn't give me any error message. Parsing it manually with `JSON.parse()` however tells me that it does not seem to be valid. At first it did the request using `$.get(...)`, which worked fine in FF but not in IE (caching problem). I thought it is a problem with german special characters (umlaut) but it is not the case. It rather seems that this always happens, when the jsonarray is of larger size (~ 50 objects and more). Unfortunately, i cannot post an example json here, since it contains sensible data.

I have wasted hours to solve this problem, so please someone has any idea about whats wrong here? Is there any tool that helps me validate my json and tell me why exactly it is invalid? or might the problem be of any else cause? Thanks.

Comment: You can used `JSON.parse()` because in response get as string so first parse json must be. If you validate json please check this https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Hey, i just did that and jsonlint as well as jsonformatter tell me my json is valid. I tried `JSON.parse()`in my ajax callback, but as i wrote it gives me an error. However, it should not be necessary to use it because i specified `"datatype": "json"` anyway.

Comment: You can try with `console.log(resultList[i].key);` or try this `resultList.result` insted of `resultList`

Comment: Thank you, but the problem is not that i don't know how to iterate over my json. The problem is, that the string response cannot be parsed TO json and i don't understand why.

Comment: You can check how your json original return what? using this `JSON.stringify(resultList);`

Comment: This sounds like a server side issue.

Comment: Thank you, but as i mentioned the requests often work normally (yet only when the json was not too large). Is there anything i should change about my servlet response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i solved the problem: The problem was in my servlet. I had to set the content encoding properties for the response AT THE BEGINNING before i add the content to the writer. So it looks like this now:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest aRequest, HttpServletResponse aResponse) 
    throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
        aResponse.setContentType("application/json");
        aResponse.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        QueryObject queryObject = new QueryObject();
        queryObject.setSearchText(aRequest.getParameter("searchText"));
        String[] types = aRequest.getParameterValues("types[]");
        queryObject.setTypes(types);
        queryObject.setResultNumber(Integer.parseInt(aRequest.getParameter("resultNumber")));

        JSONArray results = indexManager.doSearch(queryObject);

        aResponse.getWriter().write(results.toString());

        PrintWriter out = aResponse.getWriter();
        out.flush();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would comment but as i don't have 50 rep yet...

You can check if you JSON is valid with this tool https://jsonlint.com/ and about the JSON being too big I would not bet on it, there is no fixed limit on how large a JSON data block is or any of the fields (with the right amount of heap memory allocated to the jvm) . There are limits to how much JSON the JavaScript implementation of various browsers can handle (e.g. around 40MB in my experience).